# how to set sublime text to use tab to switch completion source, not commit completion?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm new to sublime text 3. I use vim mode, and set auto_complete=true.

how to make sublime text 3,  use `tab` to switch completion source to next, and `enter` to commit completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your keybindings and add:

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "move",
    "args": { "by": "lines", "forward": true },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
    ],
},
{
    "keys": ["enter"],
    "command": "commit_completion",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
    ],
},
```

Comment: great, you save my life